# README.md do not list and show on notebook server

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I am new on ipython notebook. I have installed ipython 2.3.1 on ScientificLinux6.4 (like CentOS6.4) and run it as a notebook server as described in http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/notebook/public_server.html. 
It works good so far, but I do not see the  README.md file and content in my browser. Is it normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access to non-ipynb file is not possible in the version of IPython you have installed. Next version will allow viewing and editing arbitrary text files.